# Elasticsearch group by issue on grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have some data in Elasticsearch server and I try to view them on the grafana.
Let's say there is some data, their key is "a.b", another part, their key is "a.c", 
what I want to do is group by this key, and I expected these data will be split to 2 parts.
like this:

```
"a.b" - 100
"a.c" - 200
```

But in grafana, they become 3 parts:

```
"a" - xxx
"b" - xxx
"c" - xxx
```

I tried set the index of this filed to "not_analyzed" and "no", both not work.

I just want to group them by the exact value.
How can I config grafana to reach my expectation ?

Comment: Did you reindex your index after mapping change?

Comment: @JanGaraj I delete the index, then create the index again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set field to the `keyword` type and reindex data.